# Mounting a Galxy S5 as a USB

Tags: mount, samsung

I have a Galaxy S5 and tried to use various methods to connect/mount as a USB. Went through all the steps at How to connect Android 7.1 to Ubuntu Linux with USB?

This was all using version 16.04, and have now tried it on a 18.04 version, same issues. Trying to mount is further hampered by the annoying access message on the Samsung. Pressing 'allow' doesn't give access, it simply prompts another message every few seconds.

```
$ mtp-detect libmtp version: 1.1.13

Listing raw device(s) Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung Galaxy models (MTP). Found 1 device(s): Samsung: Galaxy models (MTP) (04e8:6860) @ bus 3, dev 26 Attempting to connect device(s) ignoring libusb_claim_interface() = -6PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying again after resetting USB interface LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device LIBMTP PANIC: failed to open session on second attempt Unable to open raw device 0 OK.
```

Comment: I got it to mount ( see https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2425865&p=13886627#post13886627 for the steps), but can't see /media/myphone in Dolphin. No doubt because the user/group on that path is root ??

How do I fix that ?

Comment: Can get it to mount with jmtpfs but it seems some sort of permissions problem that is restricting access.

`ls -al /media`
ls: cannot access '/media/myphone': Input/output error
total 12
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  root  4096 Sep  1 12:06 .
drwxr-xr-x  26 root  root  4096 Sep  4 11:35 ..
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root  root    45 Jun 25  2016 .directory -> /etc/kubuntu-default-settings/directory-media
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root  root    42 Jun 25  2016 .hidden -> /etc/kubuntu-default-settings/hidden-media
d??????????  ? ?     ?        ?            ? myphone
drwxr-xr-x+  2 oygle oygle 4096 Sep  1 12:07 oygle

Comment: The following works okay, but would prefer NOT to use sudo

`sudo mkdir  /media/myphone
sudo jmtpfs /media/myphone
jmtpfs  -l #shows device
sudo ls -al /media
mount  #check if mounted
sudo  dolphin #can access files ok
sudo  bcompare #can copy/compare files ok`

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly for me ..

1. Make some path under HOME. (I had many permissions problems when trying to do this under /media )

`mkdir ~/myphone`

2. Connect the device to the USB cable
3. Ignore any messages on Ubuntu, but take the "allow" option on the Phone, if it appears
4. Use jmtpfs to mount the mtp device

`jmtpfs ~/myphone`

Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung Galaxy models (MTP).
LIBMTP ERROR: couldnt parse extension samsung.com/devicestatus:0

5. Although it gives an error, the device is available

`jmtpfs -l`

Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung Galaxy models (MTP).
Available devices (busLocation, devNum, productId, vendorId, product, vendor):
1, 9, 0x6860, 0x04e8, Galaxy models (MTP), Samsung

6. Check with the mount command ...

`mount`

jmtpfs on /home/oygle/myphone type fuse.jmtpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=10 00)

7. Also the ls command

`ls -al  ~/myphone`

total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 oygle oygle 0 Jan 1 1970 .
drwxr-xr-x 47 oygle oygle 4096 Sep 14 08:50 ..
drwxr-xr-x 15 oygle oygle 0 Apr 4 4460147 Phone

8. It can be accessed via Dolphin,etc
9. Unmount before disconnecting the cable

`fusermount -u  ~/myphone`

10. Disconnect the micro usb cable
11. I have no idea if all the various commands to modify files, shown in the tutorial at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2226702 was necessary or were used by jmtpfs. Certainly in the early stages of attempting this, those modifications were done, but IMO the tutorial was for "connecting", not mounting.